"Python not found" with PyInstaller
I am developing a GUI with PySide 6. My aim is to make it into installer and distribute to others, for this i am using PyInstaller and InnoSetup.
My GUI script runs another python file through QProcess.The code section for the same is:
 self.process = QProcess(self)
 self.process.readyReadStandardOutput.connect(self.handleStdout)
 self.process.readyReadStandardError.connect(self.handleStderr)

 self.process.start('python', ['-u', "uploader.py", "arducopter.apj"])

Here uploader.py is the other python script and arducopter.apj is the argument for the uploader.py.
I used pyinstaller with command: pyinstaller --name "my_app" --onefile main.py
With the default settings in Inno Setup, I make it into setup installer, this works fine in my pc.
When I install in another computer, I get an error:

Python not found. run without arguments to install Python

How can I resolve this?

PyInstaller loads the python interpreter internally, so there is no python executable that can be run. Do you actually need to run that script in a separate python shell? Maybe you can adjust it and make it work with the multiprocessing library.

I didn't get the part - "separate python shell", can you explain more about it? I haven't tried the multiprocessing library, i'll try and let you know how it goes.
Thanks for the help.
